# Basics for a .click(function) with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new at both jQuery and HTML in general. I was just wondering if anyone could help me out with this small jQuery script I am trying to write.

In my HTML document I have:

```
<body>
    <div class="banner"> 
       <nav> 
         <ul>
           <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I would like to, with the help of jQuery, change the whole look at the class banner which now looks like:

```
.banner {
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

I also have these styles applied for:

```
nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    padding-left:1em;
    margin-left:1em;
    border-left:1px dotted black;

}
```

Anyhow, I would like to be able to move this "banner", animate it so that it kinda slides to the top of the page, to position ~ top:10px. But only if one click on `id="about"` or `id="contact"`, if one would click home after one visited about or contact, it would go back original position.

I started to write my `my_script.js` file with just:

```
$(document.ready(function) {

   $("#about").click(function() {
    alert("hello!");

   }

});
```

To see if i even can get an alert to show by clicking, but obviously, even that was too hard for me.

If anyone could give me some advice on this, it would be very appreciated! Also, I am using `<div>` and `<nav>` tags. I'm guessing I could do without the `<div>` tags and apply the class on my `<nav>` tags? (Also very new to html5).

Comment: First of all you need to learn to use the error console. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there are some small syntax errors with your jQuery code, which can be seen in the browser console. If you use Chrome, I recommend checking out the [DevTools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview).

The errors are highlighted below in the corrected code:

```
       missing right parenthesis
          |
          v
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#about").click(function() {
    alert("hello!");
   }) // <-- missing right parenthesis
})
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCx6E/)

You should also add either `return false` or [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) after the `alert()` otherwise the browser will follow the link after alerting, which might not be what you want to happen.

I also assume you already included the jQuery library on the page somewhere, for example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or from a local source.

To answer the other parts of the question:

- Yes you could do without the `<div>`. Semantically it would be clearer to just use `<nav>`
- jQuery [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) can help with the animation/sliding, or [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

To animate the `.banner`, instead of the `alert()` you could use

```
$('.banner').animate({top:'10px'}, 1000)
return false
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCx6E/1/)

Comment: Thank you for that, now the alert does work! :) If you have any good ideas for that animation, i will gladly read it! But thank you for looking at my code! :)

Comment: Thank you for that informative answer! I do not need anything in the () at event.preventDefalut() ? Thank you once again!

Comment: I'll try to add an example animation to the answer. To answer the _preventDefault_ question, the _event_ object needs to be declared in the function to receive the event. So you need `$("#about").click(function(event)` instead. I prefer the `return false` approach if I don't need the event for anything else.

Comment: Added animation example code and updated demo :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what i wanted to learn. I tried to animate position top:15px and height:80px simultaniously, but it did not turn out as i hoped. I just added "$('.banner').animate({height:'80px'},700)" under the first animation and before return false. Any suggesstions for how to animate heigh and pos at the same time? Thank you for you time and effort! /W

Comment: It tried: $('.banner').animate({top:'10px', height:'80px'}, 1000)
Which worked. :) Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes this is the correct way! By the way, the `1000` is the animation speed in milliseconds, so you can adjust this if you want a faster or slower animation :-)

Comment: Yeah, i got aware of that, testing 10 instead of 1000.. ^^  One last thing? When i change the pos to top:100, it covers some content i have up there like a login form and a logo. Can i somehow in that same time, animate AND place it in the background of everything? :)

Comment: Somehow even I figured out to set all elements i wanted up front, in my .css file with z-index:1; Now it works like a charm! Thank you @andyb, very much for all info and help!

Comment: Yes you should be able to animate the CSS `z-index` property also. You will need a z-index on the `.banner` and the other elements you want it behind. Also there are some rules about element _stacking context_ you might need to research (or ask another question on!). See http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex for example.

Comment: Hehe, you already solved it! Good work :-)